# How should i handle Alamofire response in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier?

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, alamofire

I am trying to learn Swift and what i am trying to do is to create simple login page. Whenever user click on login button, i make a request to my web service in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier in order to check if username and password is correct. I dont want to use IBAction (like touchupinside  etc). After parsing response that comes from web service, i check if there is any error comes from web service response (like user name is not valid). If there is any error I would like to prevent segue by returning false. But i cant return false inside of Alamofire. So how should i handle it? Here is my code :

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "segueLoginToMainPage" {
        //...
        //Checking if text fields are filled or not

        else {
            let callURL : String = CONFIG.BASE_URL + "user/login"
            let parameters = [HTTPParamNames.FIELD_USER_NAME : self.txtUserName.text,
                            HTTPParamNames.FIELD_PASSWORD : self.txtPassword.text]
            Alamofire.request(.POST, callURL, parameters: parameters)
                .responseJSON { (_,_,JSON,_) in
                    var returnedData = JSON as NSDictionary
                    if returnedData["status"] as String == "error" {

                        //thats what i want to do
                        return false 
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    return true
}
```

But i cant do return false because it is async. I have found some questions like this in stackoverflow but answers are not what exactly i am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that not using IBAction is a good solution in this case but anyway there is a workaround how to achieve your goal. For this workaround you need to declare a variable typed boolean to check wether user is ready to login. Your shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier method should always return value of that variable but after you make a request. Finally after your asynchronous request finishes call the prepareForSegue method

```
var readyForLogin = false

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

if identifier == "segueLoginToMainPage" {
    //...
    //Checking if text fields are filled or not

    else  {
        if(!readyForLogin){
            let callURL : String = CONFIG.BASE_URL + "user/login"
            let parameters = [HTTPParamNames.FIELD_USER_NAME : self.txtUserName.text,
                        HTTPParamNames.FIELD_PASSWORD : self.txtPassword.text]
            Alamofire.request(.POST, callURL, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { (_,_,JSON,_) in
                var returnedData = JSON as NSDictionary
                if returnedData["status"] as String != "error" {
                    //thats what i want to do
                    self.readyForLogin = true
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueLoginToMainPage", sender: self)
                }
            }

    }}
}

return readyForLogin
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You simply should not try to use asynchronous method within `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`. Instead you should:

1. Remove segue from login button, itself.
2. Add segue between the view controllers, themselves. Specifically, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the originating scene's view controller icon (in Xcode 6+, this icon is in the bar above the scene, in earlier versions of Xcode, this icon is in the bar below the scene) to the destination scene.
3. Give this new segue a "storyboard identifier".
4. Hook up login button to an `IBAction` function.
5. In that `IBAction` function, perform your asynchronous network request, and if the login was successful, then programmatically `performSegueWithIdentifier`, supplying the storyboard identifier that you specified in step 3.

Comment: This solution requires IBAction but its how it should be done solution

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didnt want to use IBAction but it seems that it is reasonable to do in this way.